# FUSE: loopback-device in OpenVZ container

Tags: linux, filesystems, debian, fuse, openvz

I'm a customer inside an OpenVZ container (running Debian Wheezy), so I can't access the host.
Is it possible to create a loopback-device using fuse to access file-systems in files?

The administrator can't allow accessing its /dev/loop* for security reasons, I think there were trouble in the past - so this isn't a solution. All I've found is [fuse-ext2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuse-ext2/). It works, but are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible without access to the OpenVZ host as root (only your hosting provider might be able to help).

They'd need to load fuse drivers on the host and explicitly allow your container to use the fuse device. It's worth asking them, details for them are here: https://openvz.org/FUSE